# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use lambda function to multiply the column values with a floating point value, but it is  throwing the exception.

**Code snippet:**

```
m_forecasts['potential'] = m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'].apply(lambda x: x * round((m_uio + 1) / (b_uio + 1)))
```

**Error:**

```
line 374, in <lambda>   
m_forecasts['potential'] = m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'].apply(lambda x: x * round((m_uio + 1) / (b_uio + 1)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float')
```

What is the root cause for the error? Please help.

> Note: Working on Pandas 0.17 version

```
head() of bnchmk_qty column:
0    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
1    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
2    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
3    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
4    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
Name: bnchmk_qty, dtype: object
```

Comment: are m_uio and b_uio constants? there appears to be a casting issue.

Comment: @skrubber: Yes, they are constants.

Comment: what does round((m_uio + 1) / (b_uio + 1)) yeild?

Comment: a scalar value ex: 8.0

Comment: add the head of m_forecasts to your qsn

Comment: Added information

Comment: The problem is that the column values are functions. That means that `x` is a function in your lambda and you can't multiply a `function` with a `float` as the error message states.

Answer (score 2):

For me it working nice, but better is omit `apply`, because loops under the hoods:

```
m_forecasts = pd.DataFrame({'bnchmk_qty': [4.5,7.8,43.7]})

m_uio = 10.5
b_uio = 4.8
m_forecasts['potential'] = m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'] * round((m_uio + 1) / (b_uio + 1))
print (m_forecasts)
   bnchmk_qty  potential
0         4.5        9.0
1         7.8       15.6
2        43.7       87.4
```

I test code generate function column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity': {pd.Timestamp('2011-01-31 00:00:00'): 32.21, pd.Timestamp('2011-02-28 00:00:00'): 28.32, pd.Timestamp('2011-03-31 00:00:00'): 27.12, pd.Timestamp('2011-04-30 00:00:00'): 29.56, pd.Timestamp('2011-05-31 00:00:00'): 31.98, pd.Timestamp('2011-06-30 00:00:00'): 26.25, pd.Timestamp('2011-07-31 00:00:00'): 24.75, pd.Timestamp('2011-08-31 00:00:00'): 25.56, pd.Timestamp('2011-09-30 00:00:00'): 26.68, pd.Timestamp('2011-10-31 00:00:00'): 29.12, pd.Timestamp('2011-11-30 00:00:00'): 33.87, pd.Timestamp('2011-12-31 00:00:00'): 35.45}})

print (df)
            quantity
2011-01-31     32.21
2011-02-28     28.32
2011-03-31     27.12
2011-04-30     29.56
2011-05-31     31.98
2011-06-30     26.25
2011-07-31     24.75
2011-08-31     25.56
2011-09-30     26.68
2011-10-31     29.12
2011-11-30     33.87
2011-12-31     35.45
```

---

```
import statsmodels.api as sm  

p,d,q = 0,0,0
model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(endog=df['quantity'].astype(float), order=(p, d, q)).fit() ; 
fsales = model.forecast(12)[0]
print (fsales)
[29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666
 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666 29.23916666]

df['Forecast'] = fsales
print (df)
            quantity   Forecast
2011-01-31     32.21  29.239167
2011-02-28     28.32  29.239167
2011-03-31     27.12  29.239167
2011-04-30     29.56  29.239167
2011-05-31     31.98  29.239167
2011-06-30     26.25  29.239167
2011-07-31     24.75  29.239167
2011-08-31     25.56  29.239167
2011-09-30     26.68  29.239167
2011-10-31     29.12  29.239167
2011-11-30     33.87  29.239167
2011-12-31     35.45  29.239167

print(sm.version.version)
'0.8.0'
```

Comment: Tried omitting apply. But no luck.

Comment: 7.55844155844
8.0

Comment: Removed apply. But no luck.

Comment: I thin kproblem is in `m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty']` column, what return `print (m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'].head())` ?

Comment: Tried this, m_forecasts['potential'] = m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'] * 8.0

Comment: No luck. still same issue

Comment: hmm, so it seems in column is some function or something similar problem.

Comment: 0    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
1    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
2    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
3    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
4    <function multiplier at 0x1135ae230>
Name: bnchmk_qty, dtype: object

Comment: How is created column `bnchmk_qty` ?

Comment: Its  a join column:  m_forecasts['bnchmk_qty'] = m_forecasts[[]].join(
                                        bnchmark_forecasts[['quantity']])

Comment: hmm, so how is created `bnchmark_forecasts[['quantity']]` ?

Comment: model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(endog=df['quantity'].astype(float),
                                 order=(p, d, q)).fit() ;      
            fsales = model.forecast(12)[0].tolist()

Comment: list is passed to create a dataframe

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261074/2901002)? Maybe some version problem.

Comment: Statsmodels version: Its 0.6.1 version

Comment: hmm, I test my version and it is `0.8.0`, maybe some bug, because your code working nice for me

Comment: Hoo. Hmmm... can we convert the column type to some numeric type instead of function multiplier.

Comment: @JackDaniel - Hard question, but it seems not.

Comment: @JackDaniel - Just test it and add my code to answer...

Comment: You pointed me to the root. I fixed it. Thanks. My question does not justify the solution.

Comment: @JackDaniel - Yes, agree. Problem was something else.